# Convert Javascript string to literal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In python there exists ast.literal_eval(x) where if x is `"['a','b','c']"` then it will return the list `['a','b','c']`. Does something similar exist in Javascript / jQuery where I can take the array that is stored in the table cell as [x,y,z] and turn that into a literal JavaScript array?

I'd prefer to avoid any complex solutions that might be error prone since it's possible that involve splitting on the comma or escaping characters.

Edit: I should have given some better examples:

`['la maison', "l'animal"]` is an example of one that hits an error because doing a replace of a single or double quote can cause an issue since there's no guarantee on which one it'll be.

Comment: the question is not clear. Please clearly mention what will be the input & what is the expected out

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is probably what you want.

Comment: yeah, JSON.parse won't work where  "string literals"  use `'` instead of `"` .... `eval` should work though - but understand how evil eval can be

Comment: @cale_b It won't accept the string he posted, but that's a Python literal, not JSON.

Comment: @JaromandaX He asked for something "similar", I didn't think he meant it had to accept Python literals. JSON is the analogous thing for Javascript.

Comment: I understand @Barmar - was just pointing out **why** JSON.parse didn't work - funnily enough, `ast.literal_eval` has the answer in it ... `eval` :p

Comment: Is there a reason you can not output it into a valid format to begin with that is JSON and than use JSON.parse? You can use eval or Function to parse it, but it is unsafe.

Comment: @JaromandaX In Python you use `literal_eval()` to avoid the danger of a full `eval()`. We use `JSON.parse()` in Javascript for the same reason.

Comment: `a valid format` - what's invalid about `"['a','b','c']"` - sure, it isn't valid JSON, but it's still valid

Comment: I guess it depends on the trustworthiness of the source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use eval() Function like the sample bellows :

```js
// define the string to evaluate
var str_to_evaluate = 'new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW")';

// retreive the result in a array
var cars = eval(str_to_evaluate);

// print the array
console.log(cars);
```

Comment: `var str_to_evaluate = '$.ajax(...)`

Comment: simple, don't use jQuery :p

Comment: It turns out that slicing the hard brackets off, and appending the new Array ( and ) to the ends made this the best choice considering that there could be both single or double quotes.

Answer (score 9):

One could leverage [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

See below for a rough example.

```js
// String.prototype.replace() + JSON.parse() Strategy.
const input = "['a','b','c']" // Input.
const array = JSON.parse(input.replace(/'/g, '"')) // Array.
console.log(array) // Proof.
```

Although, given your update/more complex use case, [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) might be more appropriate.

```js
// eval() Strategy.
const input = `['la maison', "l'animal"]` // Input.
const dangerousarray = eval(input) // Array.
const safearray = eval(`new Array(${input.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '')})`) 
console.log(dangerousarray) // Proof.
console.log(safearray) // Proof.
```

However, the MDN docs discourage use of `eval()` due to security/speed flaws.

As a result, one may opt for an approach similar to the following:

```js
// Heavy Replacement Strategy.
const input = `['la maison', 'l\'animal']` // Input.
const array = input
  .replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '') // Remove leading and ending square brackets ([]).
  .split(',') // Split by comma.
  .map((phrase) => // Iterate over each phrase.
    phrase.trim() // Remove leading and ending whitespace.
    .replace(/"/g, '') // Remove all double quotes (").
    .replace(/^\'|\'$/g, '') // Remove leading and ending single quotes (').
  )
console.log(array) // Proof.
```